# Not able to View the data in App part in SharePoint.Working on Premise Hosting using Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007

Hey Hi Guys I am Facing Some issue Please Guide me What to do

I have made an app part and I am trying to add it Dashboard which Open when some one login in intranet in sharepoint account.I am doing the same steps as shown in above link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524232/StepplusbyplusStepplusguideplustopluscreateplusapl

But In this Link the guy has chosen sharepoint  hosting and I am using on Premise Hosting Please Guide me what should I am able to get the app part but in app part  I am getting error messages.Picture are attched with errors..

What I have done as Follows:
1)Created a client web part in VS,Code is As Follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ClientWebPart1.aspx.cs" Inherits="BI_ApplicationWeb.Pages.ClientWebPart" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Set the style of the client web part page to be consistent with the host web.
        (function () {
            'use strict';

            var hostUrl = '';
            if (document.URL.indexOf('?') != -1) {
                var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var p = decodeURIComponent(params[i]);
                    if (/^SPHostUrl=/i.test(p)) {
                        hostUrl = p.split('=')[1];
                        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + hostUrl + '/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx" />');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hostUrl == '') {
                document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/themable/corev15.css" />');
            }
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

2)Added code path to open In Iframe in Element.xml :Code is written Below

<

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ClientWebPart Name="ClientWebPart" Title="ClientWebPart Title" Description="ClientWebPart Description" DefaultWidth="800" DefaultHeight="450">


        <Content Type="html" Src="~remoteAppUrl/Pages/AppPart/ClientWebPart1.aspx" />



    <Properties>
    </Properties>

  </ClientWebPart>
</Elements>
```

3)Created page which is shown In Iframe Using below code:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming1" runat="server" />
 <div>Simple Client App Part</div>
```

Error Message I am Getting In App  Part Is Like This

```
This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address https://localhost:44300 is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the below error this https://localhost:44300. Please check whether your app is deployed or not properly.
Please use below mentioned url to create your development machine for SharePoint hosted apps
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179923.aspx

Comment: But Rahul I am just compiling the visual studio Program I am not deploying  it.I am just compiling it and when I see on ie.This error message comes their in app par and rest work good... what shoulf i do...??

Comment: Sorry unable to understand; are you doing the F5 and checking the same or how you are able to see on IE?

Comment: Yes I do f5...and than on app part it comes with the error message.

Comment: Please change in element.xml  <Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/ClientWebPart1.aspx?{StandardTokens}" />
(paste as it is) and then do the F5 you will able to see the desired result.

Comment: 1)Okay Will do it.But If i am correct ~appWebUrl works on sharepoint cloud and remoteweburl on premise hosting.... But I am doing the on premise hosting  On company Server.

Comment: Appweb work on your on-premise. For more information related to app web host web etc please see below url:- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179925.aspx